# Configuring multiple subnets with switch connected to single router interface

Tags: switch, router, switching, design

I have a design like this [image]

But I'm receiving a lot of mismatch errors and it doesn't work at all. I tried to ping 10.0.0.1 to no avail.

I'm trying to configure the vlans on the switch 1 this way (the interface that goes to the router is f0/1):

**Switch 1 configuration**

```
configure terminal 
vlan 2 
name subnet1

vlan 3
name subnet2

interface fastEthernet 0/3
switchport mode access 
switchport access vlan 3
exit

interface fastEthernet 0/2 
switchport mode access
switchport access vlan 2 
exit

interface fastEthernet 0/1 
switchport mode trunk
exit

Switch(config)#interface vlan 2
Switch(config-if)#ip address 192.168.1.3 255.255.255.0
Switch(config-if)#no shutdown

Switch(config)#interface vlan 3
Switch(config-if)#ip address 192.168.2.3 255.255.255.0
Switch(config-if)#no shutdown
```

Switch 11

```
interface fastEthernet 0/1
switchport mode trunk 
exit

**ALSO SAME CONFIG AS MAIN ROUTER WITH VLAN BEING EQUAL AS CONFIGURED BEFORE.**
```

**Update: Router config.**

```
Router>enable 
Router#configure terminal 
Router(config)#interface fastEthernet 0/0
Router(config-if)#ip address 10.0.0.1 255.255.255.0
Router(config-if)#no shutdown

Router(config)#interface fastEthernet 0/0.2
Router(config-subif)#
Router(config-subif)#encapsulation dot1Q 2
Router(config-subif)#ip address 192.168.1.2 255.255.255.0
Router(config-subif)#

Router(config)#interface fastEthernet 0/0.3
Router(config-subif)#
Router(config-subif)#encapsulation dot1Q 3
Router(config-subif)#ip address 192.168.2.2 255.255.255.0
Router(config-subif)#

Router(config)#interface FastEthernet0/0
Router(config-if)#ip helper 192.168.1.4
Router(config-if)#interface FastEthernet0/0.2
Router(config-subif)#ip helper 192.168.1.4
Router(config-subif)#interface FastEthernet0/0.3
Router(config-subif)#ip helper 192.168.1.4
Router(config-subif)#
```

I tried to also configure Switch 11 with a f0/1 trunk mode, and all the other ports to a vlan with the address 192.168.1.4

Any suggestion?

Update 1: Errors are switches Native VLAN mismatch type switch11 f0/1 with Switch1 f0/2

Update 2: I have v2 RIP routing on the router with all the related IPs.

Update 3:
**I have connectivity between PCs and PC to router. Still get switch errors/warnings**:

> %CDP-4-NATIVE_VLAN_MISMATCH: Native VLAN mismatch discovered on FastEthernet0/1 (1), with Switch FastEthernet0/2 (2).
>
> %CDP-4-NATIVE_VLAN_MISMATCH: Native VLAN mismatch discovered on
>   FastEthernet0/3 (3), with Switch FastEthernet0/1 (1).

Update 4:

Can't seem to get the DHCP server to work. I used the IP helper command on the router f0/0 interface and subinterfaces but doesn't work.

Update 5:
Show command for switch 1 f0/2 (now named switch 0. The one connected to the router):

```
Switch>show interfaces fastEthernet 0/2 switchport
Name: Fa0/2
Switchport: Enabled
Administrative Mode: static access
Operational Mode: static access
Administrative Trunking Encapsulation: dot1q
Operational Trunking Encapsulation: native
Negotiation of Trunking: Off
Access Mode VLAN: 2 (subnet1)
Trunking Native Mode VLAN: 1 (default)
Voice VLAN: none
Administrative private-vlan host-association: none
Administrative private-vlan mapping: none
Administrative private-vlan trunk native VLAN: none
Administrative private-vlan trunk encapsulation: dot1q
Administrative private-vlan trunk normal VLANs: none
Administrative private-vlan trunk private VLANs: none
Operational private-vlan: none
Trunking VLANs Enabled: All
Pruning VLANs Enabled: 2-1001
Capture Mode Disabled
Capture VLANs Allowed: ALL
Protected: false
Unknown unicast blocked: disabled
Unknown multicast blocked: disabled
Appliance trust: none
```

Update 6:
Got rid of the warnings (creating the vlans on the subnet switches and assigning the vlan to the trunk)! Now the only issue is I can't get the DHCP to work.

**Update note**: Remember there's connectivity with the Router subinterfaces 0.2 or 0.3. Ex: ping from PC to 192.168.1.2 works and between PCs on different subnets

However the errors won't stop and can't seem to get the DHCP server to work.

[I used this tutorial but it only has a main switch](https://www.technig.com/configure-inter-vlan-routing-cisco-router/)

FINAL UPDATE:
Seems like what I did was the only possible thing according to this post ["I'm afraid you can't use ip help](https://community.cisco.com/t5/switching/using-ip-helper-address-on-a-vlan-with-three-subnets/m-p/1600927/highlight/true#M161548)er-address to assign IP addresses to PCs from a secondary address scope."

So I'd need a L3 router in order to do that. I guess this is all and I'll ad a L3 router.

Comment: Welcome on this Stack Exchanges site. If you receive errors, please include them in your question. Also, please be specific in what 'does not work properly' means.

Comment: Ok I updated the post. Please check it again.

Comment: Looking on your diagram I can tell that this will not work. At least, you will be not able to route networks on 2960 switch, as it's only have Layer-2 functionality. Instead, you can configure your link to 2811 as trunk, including in it VLANs for subnet 192.168.1.0/24 and 192.168.2.0/24 and terminating them on 2811 as subinterfaces.

Comment: We need to see the configurations of the other switches.  But make sure the switch-to-switch links are all set to "switchport mode trunk"

Comment: All VLANs need to be trunked to the router if you want to talk between subnets.  The router interface must be configured with subinterfaces for each VLAN.

Comment: I updated the post. There is at least 1 sub interface on the router. Also the switch to switch and switch to router connections are set as trunk. Right now I'm configuring everything again in case of a mistake but if you spot anything please let me know.

Comment: We can help you solve this faster if you include the *full* switch and router configurations, not just bits and pieces.  Also, when you say you can't ping, where are you pinging from?

Comment: Update: I have connectivity between the router-devices and a device-device like a pc IP 192.168.1.11 to a pc with ip 192.168.2.11. BUT still get the errors on the switches.

Comment: As Ron says you need to give us a little more, however, when i see a native vlan miss-match, i use the command : show interfaces fastEthernet 0/2 switchport, this will show me the Native vlan, and may lead to resolution

Comment: psniffer Ok. Just updated the post

Comment: I meant you could use that command on each interface to see if you see any differences, however, looking back at your config and considering Zac67 response below, i would not have any ip addresses configured on my physical interface, but instead, each vlan would be a new sub-interface with the appropriate encapsulation

Comment: Look at step 5 that on the link you provided, it shows each vlan being configured as a new sub interface

Comment: Ok I updated with the entire configuration of the router and switches. If you think there's something missing, it's not, that's all I did and whatever is missing might be the solution.

Comment: Lats comment b4 i leave .... your ports from Switch to Switch, i would have them as trunks not access ports, good luck

Comment: psniffer switch to switch and switch to router are configured as trunk. Please see the config I posted.

Comment: I don't see helper addresses on the router interfaces.  That may be why DHCP isn't working.  But it's impossible to tell because you haven't provided full configurations

Comment: Oh sorry. I forgot to add that. Yes I added it to the interface and sub interfaces. I'll edit the post.

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you can provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 1):

This can't work.

The single router interface needs to be configured as a VLAN trunk for VLAN IDs 1(?) and 2. The switches must use VLAN trunking on their interconnects and on that to the router.

You need to make sure that each subnet provides proper connectivity from the end node all the way to the router.

On the router, each VLAN subinterface needs to be configured with an IP address from the subnet. In your config, 192.168.2.0/24 is missing. 10.0.0.1/24 is bound but doesn't seem to provide any connectivity anywhere.

RIP doesn't hurt but doesn't do anything either with just one router.

Comment: Please see the updated post. Switch to switch and switch to router interfaces are configured as trunk. Also the subinterfaces have the right subnet IP as the configuration shows.